# Auto height md-button

Tags: css, angular-material

I am using angular material, and so far so good.

But I am struggling with the use of md-button and how to make them auto-height. For very long text I would like the text to break down and to be displayed on multiple lines. (this should also be true in responsive)

```
<div layout="column" layout-align="center center">
  <md-button md-whiteframe="2">
         .... VERY LONG TEXT HERE ... 
  </md-button>
</div>
```

I have tried to play with the layout without any luck.

[My codepen](http://codepen.io/batmat/pen/Raqvjw)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think replease " white-space " property  in " .md-button "

Replease this Css:

```
.md-button {
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

With This Css:

```
.md-button {
  white-space: normal;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding new class to your button:

```
#new-board-btn {
    white-space: normal;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ADewB/